# How to get data from table by giving Employee Id

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing a project in flask. I have an employee id list. 
let `e_id=["E270","E453"]`

I need to get the table data of those employees. The table contains several columns and emp_id is one of the column. But in that column the employee ID s are without the first Character, which means that the ids are "270", "453" etc. So i need to get the employee data. 
I called a query

```
sql = text('select * from hris_attendance_daily where emp_id in :e_id')
result = connection.execute(sql,e_id=e_id)
```

Expected output is not coming. The output is empty
please help
thanks in advance

Comment: not the best idea to do though , `id=[]
e_id=["E270","E453"]
for i in e_id:
 lst=int(i.strip('E'))
 id.append(lst)`,......then  sql=''select * from hris_attendance_daily where emp_id in :id''....result = connection.execute(sql,id=id)`

Comment: @codenewbie is correct, except you can be a little more efficient by using a list comprehension `ids = [id[1:] for id in e_id]`